# Closed-form Ackermann variant function proof by induction

Tags: induction, computer-science, recursion

Let $A$ be a variant of the Ackermann function.

$A(m,n)$=\begin{cases}2n&\text{if }m=0\\1&\text{if }m\ge1\text{ and }n=0\\2&\text{if }m\ge1\text{ and }n=1\\A\big(m-1,A(m,n-1)\big)&\text{if }m\ge1\text{ and }n\ge2.\end{cases}

A good guess for a closed form solution to this is as follows.

$A(m,n) = 2 \uparrow^{m} n$

The up-arrow is a [notation created by Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) where a single arrow represents exponentiation, double arrow represents tetration, triple arrow represents pentation and so on.

I am trying to prove this by induction but I am stuck because there are $2$ variables to possibly induct on. I was thinking of doing double induction over $m$ and $n$ where I prove the following:

$A(m,n) \implies A(m+1,n)$

$A(m,n) \implies A(m,n+1)$

If I assume the induction hypothesis holds for some $m$ and $n$, then I find it impossible to expand expressions like $A(m, A(m+1,n-1))$ from the first implication or $A(m-1, A(m,n))$ from the second implication.

I think my assumption that my induction hypothesis holds for some $m$ and $n$ is flawed and needs to be more nuanced than that. Any advice?

Comment: You could use so called "strong induction" meaning you assume that it works for $(a,b) $ with $a\leq m$ and $b\leq n$ as the induction hypothesis. I doubt your result will work since the Ackermann-function is well researched, but go for it and try yourself out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think your definition is off a little. Your second case should be $1$, because $2^0 = 1$, etc.

Once that is fixed, your hypothesis is true. I was able to prove it in Agda.

Generally speaking, to prove something like this, it's natural for the structure of the induction to mirror the structure of the recursive definition (since in some ways, they are one and the same). So, for your case, you want an induction method based on cases:

1. $∀n. P(0,n)$
2. $∀m. P(1+m,0)$
3. $∀m. P(1+m,1)$
4. $∀m. (∀ n. P(m,n)) → ∀n. P(1+m,1+n) → P(1+m,2+n)$

This doesn't exactly match the *particular* structure of your definition in case 4, but it matches the justification for it. One recursive call is justified by decreasing on $n$ with the same $m$, and the other is justified by decreasing on $m$ with an arbitrarily large $n$.

And this isn't too difficult to derive from the normal principle of induction. To prove $∀m\ n. P(m,n)$:

- First do induction on $m$

  - Case 1 above covers the base case for this, where $m = 0$
  - For the inductive step, we are given $∀n. P(m,n)$ and need to prove $∀n. P(1+m,n)$, do this by induction on $n$

    - When $n = 0$, use case 2 above
    - When $n = 1$, use case 3 above
    - Finally, we are given $P(1+m,1+n)$ and need to prove $P(1+m,2+n)$. This is case 4 above, since we already have that $∀n. P(m,n)$

So, by using induction twice, it's possible to build the sort of induction principle that directly corresponds to the recursive structure of your modified Ackermann function. Then it should be relatively simple to prove your theorem using this principle.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask what the cases represent? Are those things I need to prove or assumptions for induction?

Comment: The 4 cases are things you need to prove to establish $∀m\ n. P(m,n)$, just like in ordinary induction you need to prove two cases to establish $∀n. P(n)$. And of course, for your problem, $P(m,n) \equiv A(m,n) = 2 \uparrow^m n$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the 4th case, shouldn't it be $∀∀m.(1+,1+)→(1+,2+)$? Also, for the final step in the induction on $n$, why do you say we are given $ (1+,1+)$? We are given $(1+,)$ as the induction hypothesis, no? and from there, I can show $P(1+m,1+n)$ and don't even need $(1+,2+)$.

Comment: You won't be able to prove $P(1+m,1+n) → P(1+m,2+n)$, because $A(1+m,2+n) = A(m, A(1+m,1+n))$. $P(1+m,1+n)$ is sufficient to rewrite the inner $A$, but you need something like $P(m, A(1+m,1+n))$ to rewrite the outer $A$.

Comment: The reason we get $P(1+m,1+n)$ is because of the two base cases for the induction on $n$. We gave explicit cases for $0$ and $1$, so the inductive step can be $Q(1+n) → Q(2+n)$. You can also prove this sort of induction using normal induction. In the $Q(n) → Q(1+n)$ case, you again split on $n$ to subdivide into $Q(0) → Q(1)$ and $Q(1+n) → Q(2+n)$ cases.

Comment: "We gave explicit cases for 0 and 1, so the inductive step can be  (1+)→(2+)."
Can you explain this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147518/discussion-between-cuffty-and-dan-doel).